# Accessing Nested Method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed my first React component that was Function based and I'm now trying to refactor it to be Class based. However, I can't seem to get it to work when trying to convert it over. I'm pretty sure that the issue is with the RenderItem method, and when I try to bind it, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. How can I bind a method that's a child of a parent method? Is this possible, and if not what would be a better solution?

Error when compiling:

```
  Line 35:10:  'state' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars
  Line 51:9:   'renderItem' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

```html
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import API from '@aws-amplify/api';
import { List } from 'antd';
import { listQuestions as ListQuestions } from '../../graphql/queries';

export default class QuestionLoader extends React.Component {
    state = {
        questions: [],
        loading: true,
        error: false,
        form: { asked: '', owner: '' },
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.GetQuestion = this.GetQuestion.bind(this);
        this.reducer = this.reducer.bind(this);
        // this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
        console.log('constructor', this);
    }

    reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'SET_QUESTIONS':
                return { ...state, questions: action.questions, loading: false };
            case 'ERROR':
                return { ...state, loading: false, error: true };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    GetQuestion() {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(this.reducer, this.state);

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchQuestions();
        }, []);

        async function fetchQuestions() {
            try {
                const questionData = await API.graphql({ query: ListQuestions });
                dispatch({ type: 'SET_QUESTIONS', questions: questionData.data.listQuestions.items });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('error: ', err);
                dispatch({ type: 'ERROR' });
            }
        }

        const renderItem = (item) => {
            console.log(this);
            return <List.Item.Meta title={item.asked} description={item.owner} />;
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List loading={this.state.loading} dataSource={this.state.questions} renderItem={this.renderItem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// export default QuestionLoader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot mix functional component and class component thing.
useEffect, useReducer are wrong one to use with class component.

Don't use bind, use arrow function to create the method. Remove constructor.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class QuestionLoader extends React.Component {
    state = {
      data: "name"
    };

    
handleClick = () => {
   this.setState({
      name:"test"
   })
}

render() {
   return (<div> {this.state.name}
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
   </div> 

} 

       
  
}
```